# How to update data with the help of PODSCMS?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-type, podscms

**Hello All,**

I know how to fetch record with the help of podscms,
But I would like to update the record fetched by podscms.
like

```
$somePod = pods('somepod')->update($my_array);
```

Anybody have some suggestion,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available in pods()->save() - http://pods.io/docs/save/

```
<?php
// Get the book item with an ID of 5
$pod = pods( 'book', 5 );

// Set the author (a user relationship field)
// to a user with an ID of 2
$pod->save( 'author', 2 );

// Set a group of fields to specific values
$data = array(
    'name' => 'New book name',
    'author' => 2,
    'description' => 'Awesome book, read worthy!'
);

// Save the data as set above
$pod->save( $data );

// Or the shorthand
$id = pods( 'yourpod', $id )->save( $data );
```

Also available is add() - http://pods.io/docs/add/

Comment: How do you save a multiple relationship? like for eg two "authors"? $pod->save( 'author', array(1,2) ) doesn't work.

Comment: As long as author is a multiple select limited to 2+ (or no limit), passing an array should work. We also support '1,2' comma separated values.